# PHP "rename" can't find a file but command line "less" can

Tags: php, file-rename

I get the following error from PHP when running from the server

> PHP Warning: rename(var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir1/papers/1632813138.pdf,var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir1/papers/00000006.pdf): No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir1/processes/generate_abstract_pages.php on line 98

If I then run

`less var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/dir1/papers/1632813138.pdf` on the command line it finds the file. I'm copy/pasting the address so it's not accidentally getting changed.

I also tried giving rename a relative path of `../papers/1632813138.pdf` but that gave the same error.

The relative path works when run in browser, `https://example.com/dir1/processes/generate_abstract_pages.php`

```
<?php

$abstract["pdf_url"] = "1632813138.pdf";
$abstractId = 7;

$pdfFilename = str_pad($abstractId, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).".pdf";

$fileRenameSuccess = rename("../papers/$abstract[pdf_url]","../papers/$pdfFilename");

echo ($fileRenameSuccess ? "y":"n");
```

Running PHP 7.1.23
Running ‪CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 (Core)‬

Comment: Does this work `rename(getcwd() . "/../papers/$abstract[pdf_url]", getcwd() . "../papers/$pdfFilename");`

Comment: Is there a reason why the first `/` is missing from the full path in `rename(var...` - I would expect `rename(/var...`

Comment: @BrettGregson That didn't work but it did show that for some reason the cwd was just "/var/www/vhosts/liftsymposium.org" so changing your code to ```rename(getcwd() . "/httpdocs/paper_indexing/papers/$abstract[pdf_url]", getcwd() . "/httpdocs/paper_indexing/papers/$pdfFilename");``` did work. So I guess that's why the relative path wasn't working

Comment: @NigelRen ah yes thank you. Adding that "/" fixes the absolute path

Comment: If you're both okay with it I'll make a wiki answer including both your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to get the current working directory of your script to make sure that it's running from where you expect for your relative path to work.

You need a starting "/" for the absolute path to work.